# How to get binary image from pgsql?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have store image in `pgsql` using Laravel like this but I am not able to get image:

```
$fi =  $params['avatar'];
$p=fopen($fi,'r');
$data=fread($p,filesize($fi));
$data=addslashes($data);
$contents= pg_escape_bytea($data);
```

When try this:

```
$user_image = User::where('id',Auth::User()->id)->pluck('avatar')->first(); 
$unese_image = pg_unescape_bytea($user_image);
```

It's giving error like this:

> pg_unescape_bytea() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

Answer (score 0):

```
User::where('id', Auth::User()->id)
```

That query is completely redundant. `Auth::user()` is going to contain the same thing as `User::where('id',Auth::User()->id)->first()`, so there is not point in calling that query.

You should simply be able to do:

```
$unese_image = pg_unescape_bytea(Auth::user()->avatar);
```

As long as `avatar` is a string, that should work.

Comment: Ya thanks for you suggestion but same error when i did like this $unese_image = pg_unescape_bytea(Auth::user()->avatar);